# Automatically dispose child lifetime scopes in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

There are many times I create a child lifetime scope in Autofac simply to replace or supplement registrations in the parent. And from that point forward, I only use the child lifetime scope. The autofac documentation states that [child scopes are not automatically disposed](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#child-scopes-are-not-automatically-disposed):

> **Child Scopes are NOT Automatically Disposed**
>
> While lifetime scopes themselves implement `IDisposable`, the lifetime scopes that you create **are not automatically disposed for you**. If you create a lifetime scope, you are responsible for calling `Dispose()` on it to clean it up and trigger the automatic disposal of components.

However, in this case, I do want children to be automatically disposed.

The workaround I've thought of so far is to have the child scope dispose the parent. Something like this:

```cs
ILifetimeScope scope = ...;
var childScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope();
childScope.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(scope);
scope = childScope;
```

Since I never keep track of `scope` past this point, only `childScope`, I need a way to dispose the parent.

To complicate matters further, each parent can have multiple child scopes. So I can't do this in those cases. I only want to dispose the parent when the last child is disposed. To do that, I think in the parent I'd have to register some service dedicated to reference counting each time `BeginLifetimeScope()` is called, and decrement that reference count when the child is disposed.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly, so I wanted to see if there's a better solution here. I'm migrating my code base from UnityContainer to Autofac. The code previously had a `UnityDisposer` object that would walk the parent/child tree from top down and dispose everything, but I don't get that kind of hierarchy with Autofac.

## Edit

There's some doubt about my speculated solution, so I wrote a sample app to see what happens:

```cs
class ThingA : IDisposable
{
    public ThingA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Construct ThingA");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose ThingA");
    }
}

class ThingB : IDisposable
{
    public ThingB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Construct ThingB");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose ThingB");
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder;

        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ThingA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        ILifetimeScope container1 = builder.Build();
        container1.Resolve<ThingA>();

        var container2 = container1.BeginLifetimeScope(builder2 =>
        {
            builder2.RegisterType<ThingB>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        });

        container2.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(container1);
        container1 = container2;

        container1.Resolve<ThingB>();

        container1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Construct ThingA
Construct ThingB
Dispose ThingB
Dispose ThingA
```

So from what I can tell, for a linear parent/child relationship, this seems to work. But it doesn't solve the multiple-child issue. And to make it clear, I'm not particularly happy with the solution for the linear case, either.

Comment: i wonder if theres a conflict here - does it even make sense to dispose a parent when a child is active? is that safe?

Comment: @DanielA.White I thought about that too, but since a parent does not dispose its child lifetime scopes, I assumed that made it safe. In any case, your question is exactly the same one I have, and is the purpose for this post.

Comment: @void.pointer Why do you want to change the variable `scope`? Why not let it as the parent being and work with `childScope` instead? But more importantely: Why not simply call `scope.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(childScope);`? That way the child scope gets disposed when the parent scope gets disposed.

Comment: Because I need to use the child scope to access its registrations. The parent scope serves only one purpose: To provide the base subset of registrations. My code base is only interested in the superset, which is only accessible from the child. And because I am not interested in keeping track of `parent`, that means I need the child to ensure it is disposed.

Comment: @void.pointer When should the child be disposed?

Comment: The child will be disposed either by me calling `Dispose()` manually or via `using`. At that time, the child should also dispose the parent, but only if it does not have other children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an Autofac perspective, you actually will have to start tracking parent and child scopes so you can choose when to dispose them. It's sort of a Spider-Man situation: With great power comes great responsibility.

Sometimes this is as easy as wrapping the set of various units of work with a `using` statement. In an async situation, like with ASP.NET, places like middleware and `HttpContext` come into play.

Disposing a parent out from under a child is a bad idea. Besides the fact that once the parent is disposed you can't really resolve things from the child (yes, I understand the parent would somehow stick around until the end of the last child, but the fact remains); we've definitely seen weird edge cases folks get themselves into by intentionally or unintentionally disposing the parent out from under the child and, depending on how it got hooked up and the order in which things happen, you can end up with really hard to troubleshoot exceptions involving `ObjectDisposedException`.

If you think about what you're trying to do *outside* of an Autofac context, it's kind of a bad design pattern to try to have the system dispose of itself, like having the child scope somehow responsible for the parent. For example, if you had some other parent/child relationship where you wanted to do this, more often you'd see some sort of external orchestrator that handles reference counts and disposal - outside the logical parent/child relationship.

I would recommend doing something like that instead - **actually track the parent and child scopes with some nature of orchestrator class** and have the orchestrator watch for all the child scopes to disappear.

Plus, it'll make other situations easier, like "I created the parent, I created one child, it got disposed and cleaned up the parent while I was trying to create a second child." Threading stuff. You'll be able to account for that in your orchestrator code.

Comment: I looked at the Autofac code. The disposer is disposed right after the CurrentScopeEnding event is invoked. So semantically, disposing a parent in either of these locations will not change the issue here. And an orchestrator would need to rely on the CurrentScopeEnding callback to dispose the parent. The only way to do it safely would be to "queue" the disposal of the parent to happen after the child is disposed, but this is complicated and nasty. The `LifetimeScope.Dispose()` code doesn't indicate an issue with disposing a parent while the child is being disposed.

Comment: Having said that, the orchestrator implementation is where I went with this, it's cleaner, and the orchestrator itself is set up with `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` so each "parent" container owns one, it keeps track of child scopes, and watches for them ending and then it disposes its owning scope. The solution is a lot more flexible, as you say, even though it represents an anti-pattern...